# Iterating through a social graph in a SQL database

Tags: sql, recursion, graph, sql-server-2012

I store simple social-graph information like so:

```
People ( PersonId bigint, Name nvarchar )
Relationships ( From bigint, To bigint, Title nvarchar )
```

So the data looks something like this:

```
People
1, John Smith
2, Joan Smith
3, Jack Smith

Relationships
1, 2, Spouse
1, 3, Parent
2, 3, Parent
```

Note that the titles of relationships are normalized: so there is no "husband" and "wife", only "spouse", which also avoids needing to create two separate relationships that form the same link, the same applies with "Parent" instead of "Son" or "Daughter".

The question is how you can iterate through an entire connected-graph (i.e. only return a single family), and, for example, find siblings without needing to create an explicit Sibling relationship entry. The nodes don't necessarily need to be returned in any particular order. I might also want to only return nodes that are at most `N` degrees away from a given start node.

I know you can do recursive SQL SELECT statements with some new tricks in recent SQL language versions, but this isn't necessarily a recursive operation because these relationships can express a cyclic non-directional graph (think if "Friend" was added as a relationship). How would you do that in SQL?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2012, thanks!

Comment: Very intresting question. Could you elaborate on your exact question?
Your question can be "Find siblings from `People` and `Relationships`."
If possible, could you show us an example result set you are expecting?

Comment: Do you know http://www.neo4j.org/? It claims to be blazing fast at computing these relations.

Answer (score 2):

Very cool problem.  While it's a social network graph, it is still a hierarchical problem, even though the hierarchy can logistically turn into a web of interconnections.  In MSSQL you still want to use a `WITH` clause to do a recursive query, the only difference is that due to the multiple interconnections you need to ensure unique results, either with `DISTINCT` or by using an `IN` clause in the `WHERE` condition.

This works:

```
DECLARE @PersonID bigint;
SET @PersonID = 1;

WITH RecurseRelations (PersonID, OriginalPersonID)
AS
(
    SELECT  PersonID, PersonId OriginalPersonID
    FROM    People

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  ToPersonID, RR.OriginalPersonID
    FROM    Relationships R
                    INNER JOIN
            RecurseRelations RR
                    ON
                R.FromPersonID = RR.PersonID
)
SELECT  PersonId, Name
FROM    People
WHERE   PersonId IN 
        (               
            SELECT  PersonID
            FROM    RecurseRelations
            WHERE   OriginalPersonID = @PersonID
        )
```

Here's some test data with more relations than you had originally and a whole other family to make sure it's not picking up more than intended.

```
create table People ( PersonId bigint, Name nvarchar(200) );
create table Relationships ( FromPersonID bigint, ToPersonID bigint, Title nvarchar(200) );

insert into People values (1, 'John Smith');
insert into People values (2, 'Joan Smith');
insert into People values (3, 'Jack Smith');
insert into People values (4, 'Joey Smith');
insert into People values (9, 'Jaime Smith');

insert into People values (5, 'Edward Jones');
insert into People values (6, 'Emma Jones');
insert into People values (7, 'Eva Jones');
insert into People values (8, 'Eve Jones');

insert into Relationships values (1, 2, 'Spouse');
insert into Relationships values (1, 3, 'Parent');
insert into Relationships values (2, 3, 'Parent');
insert into Relationships values (3, 4, 'Child');
insert into Relationships values (2, 4, 'Child');
insert into Relationships values (4, 9, 'Child');

insert into Relationships values (5, 6, 'Spouse');
insert into Relationships values (5, 7, 'Parent');
insert into Relationships values (6, 7, 'Parent');
insert into Relationships values (5, 8, 'Child');
```